# VBA code to reset command button sizes and place them at specific named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 - I have a number of named Command Buttons and Toggle Buttons that tend to move around or get set to a height and width of 0 so I want to add vba code to reset the command buttons and toggle buttons sizes and locate them at a specific named range.

For example names cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4 to be set at range names cbrn1, cbrn2, cbrn3, cbrn4 respectively with a width of 20 and height of 20 and tb1, tb2, tb2, tb4 to be set at range names tbrn1, tbrn2, tbrn3, tbrn4  with a width of 10 and height of 10. How would I do this by using an if then loop?

Your help would be more than appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactally on your question. But I am just trying to be helpful. You are trying to set the sizes in code? you can make a default size function size(20,20) for the typeof(control) If I had a small code clip I could be more helpful. you said 2010 so I am assuming .net even though VBA usually refers to pre-.net ie vb 4,5,6

```
For each obj as Control in Me.Controls  
Select case typeof obj
     if typeof (obj) is ComboBox then
             obj.size = (20,20)
     elseif typeof(obj) is ToggleButton then
             obj.size = (0,0)
     end if
next
```

tried to use spaces there to make it more readable. This code is not exact. but if I am correct on the type of question you are asking this "pseudo-code" should help it did not format correct hope it does this time if not. should still get the idea

Comment: looking for VBA macro coding for Excel.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for VBA macro coding that will work in Excel. This looks like visual basic programming which I don't think will work.